# Formula for spring constant $k$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

Is there a formula for the spring constant $k$ which satisfies the equation $$F=k\Delta \ell~?$$ 
A similar question was asked but was answered by transposition of this equation... I'm hoping for an answer addressing the physical meaning of a spring constant.

Unlike the question which is marked as a duplicate, I was hoping for a fixed equation which encompasses all factors, rather than just a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximating a little bit, we can find Young's modulus as the ratio between stress and strain with the formula $E=σ/e=\frac{FL_0}{A\Delta L}$.

From that, we get $$F=\frac{EA\Delta L}{L_0}$$
Hence $$k=\frac{EA}{L_0}$$

Answer (score 2):

The elastic constant of the spring depends on the geometry of the spring. There are formulas relating spring constant to the spring dimensions for various conditions.
For a helical spring, a first approximation formula is
$$ k= \frac{Gd^4}{8ND^3} $$
where G is the shear modulus, d is the diameter of the wire, N is the number of coils and D is the diameter of the spring.
If the extension of the spring is "large" or the ration d/D is not small enough the formula needs extra terms. You can look up papers discussing the details of different springs. 
For helical springs, google "On the spring constant of a close-coiled helical spring"

Comment: I did not use the Research Gate link. There are more hits below that one.